# After converting timestamp to datetime and back - where does the difference come from?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

Because using timestamp leads to a better performance in mysql I want to save the time as timestamp in my database. I receive a datetime string like this: 2014-09-24 17:18:27, convert it to timestamp with `strtotime($the_date_from_above)` and just for fun I converted it back with `date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime($the_date_from_above))`

I var_dumped the process:

```
string(19) "2014-09-24 17:18:27"
int(1411579107)
string(19) "2014-09-24 17:09:27"
```

What went wrong during the time string convert? What is causing the difference? It's the same amount of seconds but 9 minutes difference is strange.

Comment: try with this date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($the_date_from_above))

Comment: Date format 'm' stands for month. Use 'i' for minute.

Comment: [You don't need to convert it to **`TIMESTAMP`** and you can use **`DATE_FORMAT`** to format it any way you need as long as your column type is of **`TIMESTAMP`** or **`DATETIME`** in your database table.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to convert it back like this:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($the_date_from_above))
```

When you convert it your way the `m` in `H:m:s` gets treated as the month.

Even nicer would be to use the datetime class:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date = $date->setTimestamp($yourtimestamp);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Good catch on `m` and `i`

Comment: Even nicer to use MySQL directly :) as his date format doesn't need to be converted.

Answer (score 1):

```
date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime($the_date_from_above))
        ^-----^---
```

you use `m` twice, which is the MONTHS value. Minutes are actually `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You simply use wrong date-time template "Y-m-d H:m:s" should be "Y-m-d H:i:s". Little mistake.

But what I don't understand is your reason to do it this way. Because MySql has correct column type for saving Date-Time values and type timestamp is usually use for another purpose.

For better performance and precision, if you want to use value for next calculation, can sense save in database this value as string. (means timestamp with miliseconds)